# does TFS easily allow you to share testresults with people who don't have TFS?

Tags: tfs

I'd like to publish a set of test results to a place where team members who don't have TFS can see the results. Does TFS do anything like this easily? I see that that test results do get published, but without a TFS license I don't see any way for people to view them.

I think I can do this easily by pulling the XML from the test results and then pushing that out to a central location, but I was wondering if there's anything like an "official" way to do this.

TFS is hard to work with when you have some people who have access to it and others who don't... I really wish there was some sort of read-only access to the server (let people get files but not check them out for instance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No official way that I know of.  Your idea of putting the .trx files in a central location should be OK as a manual workaround.

The question that comes to mind though is why don't you have everyone on TFS?  If you're all part of the same team then not having everyone on the same source control/issue tracking system sees a little strange.

Comment: The people who aren't on TFS are in the QA and UAT dept. I'd like to be able to share files that are in source with them but I can't because they don't have licenses. And getting licenses for them probably won't happen because of the expense.

Comment: Understood.  It's a shame, but it looks like you're stuck with the central file share option (or use a sharepoint server).